# jQuery nth-child selector skipping numbers

Tags: jquery, html, css-selectors

I'm kind of a beginner at jquery, so I probably wouldn't understand too much advanced stuff, but here's the problem: when I try to select the `nth-child(1)`, it selects the first one, as expected (I know I can use first child, but I don't feel like it). However, if it's changed to `nth-child(2)`, nothing is selected. `nth-child(3)` selects `Something2`, and `nth-child(5)` selects `something3`. This is too much for me!

```
<div id="navigation">
    <a href="#">Something</a> <br />
    <a href="#">Something2</a> <br />
    <a href="#">Something3</a> <br />
</div>

<script>
$('#navigation').find(">:nth-child(1)").css("font-weight", "bold");
</script>
```

Comment: could be that it's selecting the br tag? What's with the less than sign btw?

Comment: I saw it on some other question. Is it required? guess not

Comment: Perhaps you could try finding all 'a'  elements and using eq() to get a certain one.

Comment: `>` is the child selector http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#child-combinators

Comment: it WAS! I missed something big. Well, still a beginner! the br tag, that is

Comment: I don't think you need the child selector if you're using find (). It is looking through children.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`:nth-child(1)`  should be selecting the second element, as the index you pass in is zero based.

The problem is that your selector was including the `<br />` tags, which isn't expected (from my point of view).

HTML:

```
<div id="navigation">
    <a href="#">Something</a> <br />
    <a href="#">Something2</a> <br />
    <a href="#">Something3</a> <br />
</div>​
```

JavaScript:

```
$('#navigation').children().not('br').eq(1).css("font-weight", "bold");​
```

[**Live Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/tZDnp/4/)

Comment: Eq() is the easy to go. I think you should search through a tags though instead of not(br)

Comment: I understand that selecting only a elements to search may be more readable (i'm not sure of the performance comparison) however if OP was merely using <a> elements for the purposes of demonstrating his issue on SO, I thought it would make sense to exclude elements that you'd almost never want to include.

Answer (score 0):

The nth-child selector is a bit confusing at first because it's the nth-child of the parent, not just the nth-child matching that selector of the parent, the selector has no bearing the position for this selector.

To get the div you want, do 3n+1 like this:

```
$('#navigation:nth-child(3n+1)').css("font-weight", "bold");
```